# Projeto Java com Oracle e MySQL ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tendo em vista um BD Oracle e um BD MySQL, e a impossibilidade de integração de ambas as bases:

Seria possível, por exemplo, uma classe de minha aplicação 'olhar' para a tabela mysql e atualizar uma tabela oracle?

Comment: Sim, seria possível.

Comment: O comentário acima já responderia sua dúvida. Tente especificar melhor qual seu problema. Leia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei você pode abrir duas conexões com bancos de dados diferentes e então inserir os dados lidos de um banco de dados no outro mais ou menos assim:

```
String urlMySql = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/seu_database_mysql";
String urlDb2 = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/seu_database_db2";

Connection connMySql = DriverManager.getConnection(urlMySql);
Connection connDb2 = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDb2);

PreparedStatement selectDb2 = connDb2.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TABELA");
ResultSet rsDb2 = selectDb2.executeQuery();

while (rsDb2.next()) {
 PreparedStatement insertMySql = connMySql.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO OUTRA_TABELA VALUES...");
insertMySql.setXXX(rsDb2.getXXX(...));
insertMySql.executeUpdate();
}
```

Daí, tudo o que você tem que fazer é gerenciar os Connections, PreparedStatements e ResultSets como de costume (inclusive fechando-os em um bloco finally ou usando o try-with-resources).

Também é válido encapsular os Connections em DAOs, colocar as conexões em pools ou separar qualquer operação com o banco de dados em várias classes e/ou vários métodos. Apenas tenha em mente que poderá haver mais do que uma conexão com o banco de dados ativa ao mesmo tempo (juntamente com os respectivos PreparedStatements e ResultSets).

Comment: Muito bom! a minha duvida era justamente "Apenas tenha em mente que poderá haver mais do que uma conexão com o banco de dados ativa ao mesmo tempo". Obrigado!